# Set flask route defaults from current app config

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I want to get the route args default value from current flask application config but I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/hamid/projects/bfl/develop.py", line 4, in <module>
    application = create_app(DevelopmentConfig)
  File "/home/hamid/projects/bfl/project/application.py", line 56, in create_app
    configure_blueprints(app)
  File "/home/hamid/projects/bfl/project/application.py", line 97, in configure_blueprints
    bp = __import__('project.apps.%s' % blueprint_name, fromlist=['views'])
  File "/home/hamid/projects/bfl/project/apps/store/views/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .store import *
  File "/home/hamid/projects/bfl/project/apps/store/views/store.py", line 193, in <module>
    @mod.route('/<page>/', defaults={'per_page': current_app.config['PAGE_SIZE']})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

And here is my sample code:

```
@mod.route('/<page>/', defaults={'per_page': current_app.config['PAGE_SIZE']})
@mod.route('/<per_page>/<page>/')
@login_required
def index(per_page, page):
    pagination_obj = Pagination(Store.objects(is_dealer=False), per_page, page)
    return render('store/index.html', pagination=pagination_obj)
```

Any idea how can I get rout default values from current application config?

Answer (score 3):

current_app can only access "config" dictionary within ["request context"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/).

To access config value outside request context, you can use this custom method :

```py
from . import app
def getConfig(key):
    with app.app_context():
        if key in current_app.config:
            return current_app.config.get(key)
        else:
            raise Exception("Custom Message")
```

Answer (score -1):

You code looks ok.

As the error is raised in the line where you have `current_app.config['PAGE_SIZE']`, can you debug and confirm that this variable actually exists?

By the `@mod` decorator, I guess you are using blueprints. So maybe `current_app` is not the name of your app, or you haven't imported `current_app` properly. Or, yet, you are not setting the config variables for you app properly.

Finally, in what context you get this error? Accessing which URL? Or is it in a test environment?

In sum: the mistake probably is not in the bit of code you shared.

Comment: Yes I'm using blueprints. But when using blueprint does current app make any difference? I've imported current app from `flask.current_app`. and the config variables works OK and existed. But as you can see trace-back says it isn't in app context!!

Comment: I raised the thing with Blueprints because when people don't use them, usually they have the same name for the decorator (eg `@app`) and for the application (and its objects; eg `app.config['SOME_CONFIG']`). But this is not your case… As I said, the mistake is probably elsewhere. So, honestly, I don't know what else to say if you don't share the bits where you create the app, register the config variables, import things into this Blueprint definition, how you get this error etc.

Comment: Well… try something: replace `current_app.config['PAGE_SIZE']` by any given integer. If it works, the problem is that in the `current_app` object. For example: put `@mod.route('/<page>/', defaults={'per_page': 42]})`, run the server and come back :)

Comment: @HamidFzM Looks like Deepak's answer got it! Have you tested it? Please, share here whatever works so I learn too…